# Create a new column evaluating values in previous column

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from an imported df from excel like that:

| Lev. | Material | Text | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .1 | X222 | Model3 | 1 |
| .2 | 4027721 | Gruoup1 | 1 |
| .3 | 4647273 | Gruoup1.1 | 4 |
| .3 | 573828 | Gruoup1.2 | 1 |
| .2 | 47883 | Gruoup2 | 1 |
| .3 | 573829 | Gruoup2.1 | 5 |
| .3 | 747458 | Gruoup2.2 | 4 |

I want to add a new column reporting a specific value, obtained after an evaluation of the column Lev.
I tried to use a if command like that:

```
def categorise_row:   
 if df ["Lev"] == ".1" or ".2"
   df ["Material"] 
 else df.iloc[-1]["Material"] 
df ['ColF'] = df.apply (categorise_row)
```

The result has to be, if Lev = .1 or .2 the value present in column material instead, the result has to be equal to the result present in the new column upper row.

Expected result:

| Lev. | Material | Text | QTY | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .1 | X222 | Model3 | 1 | X222 |
| .2 | 4027721 | Gruoup1 | 1 | 4027721 |
| .3 | 4647273 | Gruoup1.1 | 4 | 4027721 |
| .3 | 573828 | Gruoup1.2 | 1 | 4027721 |
| .2 | 47883 | Gruoup2 | 1 | 47883 |
| .3 | 573829 | Gruoup2.1 | 5 | 47883 |
| .3 | 747458 | Gruoup2.2 | 4 | 47883. |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where` to hide values from other levels and use `ffill` to broadcast the last valid to bottom rows:

```
df['ColF'] = df['Material'].where(df['Lev.'].isin(['.1', '.2'])).ffill()
print(df)

# Output
  Lev. Material       Text  QTY     ColF
0   .1     X222     Model3    1     X222
1   .2  4027721    Gruoup1    1  4027721
2   .3  4647273  Gruoup1.1    4  4027721
3   .3   573828  Gruoup1.2    1  4027721
4   .2    47883    Gruoup2    1    47883
5   .3   573829  Gruoup2.1    5    47883
6   .3   747458  Gruoup2.2    4    47883
```